# Python regex to find characters unsupported by XML 1.0 returns no results

Tags: python, xml, regex, unicode, python-3.x

I'm writing a Python 3.2 script to find characters in a Unicode XML-formatted text file which aren't valid in XML 1.0. The file itself isn't XML 1.0, so it could easily contain characters supported in 1.1 and later, but the application which uses it can only handle characters valid in XML 1.0 so I need to find them.

XML 1.0 doesn't support any characters in the range \u0001-\u0020, except for \u0009, \u000A, \u000D, and \u0020. Above that, \u0021-\uD7FF and \u010000-\u10FFFF are also supported ranges, but nothing else. In my Python code, I define that regex pattern this way:

```
re.compile("[^\u0009\u000A\u000D\u0020\u0021-\uD7FF\uE000-\uFFFD\u010000-\u10FFFF]")
```

However, the code below isn't finding a known bad character in my sample file (\u0007, the 'bell' character.) Unfortunately I can't provide a sample line (proprietary data).

*I think the problem is in one of two places: Either a bad regex pattern, or how I'm opening the file and reading in lines—i.e. an encoding problem.* I could be wrong, of course.

Here's the relevant code snippet.

`processChunkFile()` takes three parameters: `chunkfile` is an absolute path to a file (a 'chunk' of 500,000 lines of the original file, in this case) which may or may not contain a bad character. `outputfile` is an absolute path to an optional, pre-existing file to write output to. `verbose` is a boolean flag to enable more verbose command-line output. The rest of the code is just getting command-line arguments (using `argparse`) and breaking the single large file up into smaller files. (The original file's typically larger than 4GB, hence the need to 'chunk' it.)

```
def processChunkFile(chunkfile, outputfile, verbose):
    """
    Processes a given chunk file, looking for XML 1.0 chars.
    Outputs any line containing such a character.
    """
    badlines = []

    if verbose:
        print("Processing file {0}".format(os.path.basename(chunkfile)))

    # open given chunk file and read it as a list of lines
    with open(chunkfile, 'r') as chunk:
        chunklines = chunk.readlines()

        # check to see if a line contains a bad character;
        # if so, add it to the badlines list
        for line in chunklines:
            if badCharacterCheck(line, verbose) == True:
                badlines.append(line)

    # output to file if required
    if outputfile is not None:
        with open(outputfile.encode(), 'a') as outfile:
            for badline in badlines:
                outfile.write(str(badline) + '\n')

    # return list of bad lines
    return badlines



def badCharacterCheck(line, verbose):
    """
    Use regular expressions to seek characters in a line
    which aren't supported in XML 1.0.
    """
    invalidCharacters = re.compile("[^\u0009\u000A\u000D\u0020\u0021-\uD7FF\uE000-\uFFFD\u010000-\u10FFFF]")
    matches = re.search(invalidCharacters, line)
    if matches:
        if verbose:
            print(line)
            print("FOUND: " + matches.groups())
        return True

    return False
```

Answer (score 1):

```
\u010000
```

Python `\u` escapes are four-digit only, so that U+0100 followed by two U+0030 Digit Zeros. Use capital-U escape with eight digits for characters outside the BMP:

```
\U00010000-\U0010FFFF
```

Note that this and your expression in general won't work on ‘narrow builds’ of Python where strings are based on UTF-16 code units and characters outside the BMP are handled as two surrogate code units. (Narrow build were the default for Windows. Thankfully they go away with Python 3.3.)

> it could easily contain characters supported in 1.1 and later

(Although XML 1.1 can only contain those characters when they're encoded as numeric character references `&#...;`, so the file itself may still not be well-formed.)

> open(chunkfile, 'r')

Are you sure the chunkfile is encoded in `locale.getpreferredencoding`?

> The original file's typically larger than 4GB, hence the need to 'chunk' it.

Ugh, monster XML is painful. But with sensible streaming APIs (and filesystems!) it should still be possible to handle. For example here, you could process each line one at a time using `for line in chunk:` instead of reading all of the chunk at once using `readlines()`.

> re.search(invalidCharacters, line)

As `invalidCharacters` is already a compiled pattern object you can just `invalidCharacters.search(...)`.

Having said all that, it still matches U+0007 Bell for me.

Comment: Thanks bobince - that's a lot of useful general (and specific!) advice, and I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way to remove words, characters, strings or anything between two known tags or two known characters in a string is by using a direct and Native C approach using RE along with a Common as shown below.

```
var = re.sub('<script>', '<!--', var)
var = re.sub('</script>', '-->', var)
#And finally
var = re.sub('<!--.*?-->', '', var)
```

It removes everything and works faster, better and cleaner than Beautiful Soup. Batch files are where the "" got there beginnings and were only borrowed for use with batch and html from native C". When using all Pythonic methods with regular expressions you have to realize that Python has not altered or changed much from all regular expressions used by Machine Language so why iterate many times when a single loop can find it all as one chunk in one iteration? Do the same individually with Characters also.

```
var = re.sub('\[', '<!--', var)
var = re.sub('\]', '-->', var)
#And finally
var = re.sub('<!--.*?-->', '' var)#wipes it all out from between along with.
```

And you do not need Beautiful Soup. You can also scalp data using them if you understand how this works.